# Setting Up a Load-Balancing Linux-Based Router with Two Internet Connections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router, local-area-network

(Sorry for the wall of text. There are specific questions at the bottom, but lacking experience, I would greatly appreciate any comments on the software choices and general recommendations from the generous community.)

I'm planning/trying to set up a linux-based software router (the "server") for our small office. The main use case is to load-balance internet access between the internal LAN and (at least) two connections to the outside world (i.e. the internet.)

We have about 30 computers (the "clients",) connected with wire to ~10 unmanaged switches, which in turn are connected to a single unamanged switch that sits at the root of our connection tree. The "server" is also plugged into this root switch. All of these clients run Windows, with a couple of Mac and Linux boxes.

In addition, there are ~50 wireless devices (cellphones, tablets, and occasional laptops) that connect to one of 5 WiFi access points that are connected to any one of the various switches above. These need internet access as well, but are considered secondary citizens in our setup.

The main functions of the server will be:

1. Provide internet access to the whole office, utilizing all the available ISP connections (currently two.) For this, I'll either configure `iptables{2}` as per the many guides online, or use some specialized software, e.g. [Net-ISP-Balance](http://lstein.github.io/Net-ISP-Balance/).
2. Act as the DHCP server for all devices.
3. Serve our `git` repositories and various Samba shares. (This is the part that I have done several times before and anticipate the least problems from. Fingers crossed!)
4. (This one is optional but desirable.) I also want to run something like a RADIUS server as well, and authenticate each user/device that connects to the network (and to the internet, via our network.) While we don't particularly need to restrict anybody's access, I'm hoping to have real-time bandwidth usage reports for each person/device, and maybe to be able to extract estimated work hours from them.

Now, here are my specific questions, but I very much appreciate any and all other suggestions and comments:

1. I'm planning to use generic Ubuntu server (probably 18.04 LTS) and not some mission-specific distro (e.g. [Zeroshell](https://zeroshell.org/) or the like.) I don't think this is going to cause any problems (apart from maybe more configuration file edits, etc.) Am I correct in my assumption?
2. Does the community have any comments on implementing/configuring the load-balancing between internet connections? I don't have any specific QoS or other restrictions and from my perspective, the ISP connections are identical (except maybe their speeds.) I have never configured a router before, but I (think I) understand the concepts and protocols involved (But I just need static route tables, right?)
3. What DHCP server should I use? I only have at most ~100 connected devices, and may even opt for static IP assignment (plus a "guest" WiFi SSID for, well, guests.)
4. Is RADIUS the correct protocol for my use case? I want my colleagues to log in whenever they want to begin their work, which will enable internet access for their device, and perhaps also log out before they leave the office (or more realistically, be logged out after an hour of inactivity because they have forgotten to log out.)
5. If RADIUS is the correct tool, what server software should I use?
6. If RADIUS is the correct tool, what client software can I use? I need Windows, Android, iOS, and OSX clients.
7. Generally, I don't have any internal security worries, as all of us should basically have access to everything. But most of our accesses (git, RADIUS, WiFi, etc.) are authenticated either using keypairs (git) or passwords (for everything else, except Samba, which is basically free-for-all.) It would greatly simplify my life if there were a single place to manage my users and passwords. I don't need anything extravagant, maybe I would create a Linux user for each real user and go from there. Any hints would be appreciated again.
8. Is [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) still a good choice for administration of this "server" from my own workstation? I used to used it back in the day, and don't know whether the community has moved on to something better or not.

Thank you all.

Comment: You have a decent sized list of requirements, which is good. However: 1) Server Fault does not recommend software or products, you select those  and 2)  The scope of this question is too broad, it covers user auth, layer 4 or 7 firewall, DHCP, multi ISP WAN, WiFI.  Design a WAN and campus network, hire consulting help if you need it.  Then ask a more focused question.

Comment: To sort out some questions: RADIUS and [WPA Enterprise/802.1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) is _de facto_ the only option for network access control of wireless users (PSK is **not** an option). You can set up 802.1X authentication for wired users too. Only the RADIUS server and the authenticators (WiFi APs, switches or [hostapd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd)) need to speak RADIUS, the user devices just need (and usually have) a WPA supplicant.